# Writing to stdout except for output redirection C

Tags: c, tty, stdout

I have to make a simple app for school.

I have to write arguments one per line on the terminal, and return on stdout the user choices.

For example, I write `cat my_app main.c main.h`, if the user choose `main.c`, then I return `main.c` to cat. The problem is that if I write the menu on the standard output (aka STDOUT_FILENO), I return it to `cat`. I could write my menu on STDERR, but it's a little ugly.

I don't really know how to use devices/files like `/dev/tty*` or `/dev/pty*`, but I feel I could use them to write something on the terminal without having to write it on STDOUT or STDERR.

Basically, I want to open a new output, which would be shown by the terminal (STDOUT, STDERR, MYOUT).

I don't know if I explained it correctly.

Comment: Why do you want to use `cat`? Do you want to output the contents of the file selected?

Comment: The rule is to output the user selection. For example, cat would show content of the user selection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To build an interactive application you can open `/dev/tty`, it will return a file descriptor to the controlling terminal:

```
int ttyfd = open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR);
```

You can use it instead of `STDIN_FILENO` or `STDOUT_FILENO` (those could be redirected to something different than the terminal when the program is started).

---

Here is some example:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
  int ttyfd = open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR);
  printf("fd: %d\n", ttyfd);
  write(ttyfd, "hello tty!\n", 11);
  return 0;
}
```

When invoked with `./test >out`, it should print the hello message on the terminal and something like `fd: 3` in the `out` file.

Comment: Currently, open returned 0, so standard output. Does it mean, writing there (same fd as std* or not) will write on the console but NOT in the standard output?

Comment: @Max13: I added some example, the `open` call should return the first non allocated fd number (usually 3 unless you make some strange redirections). Does it work for you?

Comment: Also note that I used `open` because you mentioned STDOUT_FILENO, but if you want a FILE* (like stdout) then you should use `fopen`.

Comment: @Max13 In an application that has a terminal UI, you would use `/dev/tty` for both input and input, and not care what file descriptor it's opened on.

Comment: @Gilles: for both input and input, but also for output :o)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Thank you, it solves my issue.

Comment: Great solution! If anyone is interested, I made into a handy program called [ftty](https://github.com/jocap/ftty).